# i'm trying to find and remove loop from a linked list but it doesn't work

Tags: c, loops, linked-list

```
class Solution
{
    public:
    //Function to remove a loop in the linked list.
    void removeLoop(Node* head)
    {
        Node *slow=head,*fast=head,*current=head,*prev;
        
        while(fast!=0 && fast->next!=0){
            
          slow=slow->next;
          fast=fast->next->next;
          
          if(slow==fast) break;
         
        } 
         
         while(current!=slow){
               prev=slow;
              current=current->next;
              slow=slow->next;
           } 
          prev->next=NULL;
      
        
        // code here
        // just remove the loop without losing any nodes
    }
};
```

Comment: *"it doesn't working"*: what exactly is not working? For which list?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: after checking whether the loop is present or not in the given link list , i have to remove the loop .